# Partial view doesn't go to the correct place

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

**Partial View** doesn't go to the correct place and a new page opens always.

I need to open **Partial View** at the correct place (index.cshtml). How to fix it?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{ 
  public PartialViewResult LatestNews()
  {
     var p = new Person();
     p.FirstName = " NAME " + DateTime.Now; // To test only
     return PartialView("_News", p);
  }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click here!", "LatestNews", "Home", 
   new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "latestNewsDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", LoadingElementId = "progress" })

<div id="latestNewsDiv">
</div>

<div id="progress">
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

`_News.cshtml` is under **Shared** folder

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Person
<h2>News !!!</h2>
<div>
    @Model.FirstName
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

---

Thanks to Darin Dimitrov

Initially I put

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

at the `HEAD` section

but when I put it at the bottom of the `body` tag and AFTER the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` it is working fine!

```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
         @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page. And this script inclusion should obviously happen after `jquery.js`. And if you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 bundles you should simply render the `~/bundles/jqueryval` bundle in your Layout, just after jquery:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

If you don't have the `jquery.unobtruisve-ajax.js` script included in your markup after jquery, the `Ajax.*` helpers are pretty useless. All they do is generate dummy HTML5 `data-*` attributes on the corresponding DOM elements but without the proper script there's absolutely nothing to interpret those attributes and AJAXify the elements.